# Is "roll" the natural verb to use in this sentence: Vince "rolls" up to the bar

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs

If it has been made clear in my story that Vince is in a wheelchair, would "roll" be the most natural verb to use in the below sentence:

> Vince rolls up to the bar.

Answer (score 1):

"rolls" would be a very reasonable verb to use. It does tend to emphasize that Vince is in a wheelchair, which may or may not be what you want. if you don't, a more general verb such as "comes up to", or "proceeds to", or just "goes to" might work better. This is a matter of style and emphasis.